# JNA with strings for chown instead of int?

Tags: java, linux, jna, chown

Hi i need to change the user/group of certain Files through JAVA. I have seen roughly the same Posix example evrywhere.

```
  public interface POSIX extends Library {
    public int chmod(String filename, int mode);
    public int chown(String filename, int userId, int groupId);
    }
```

The problems with this is that you have to know the PID and GID, but to do that you will have to pass throught Runtime to get them and so i don't really see the use of chown method. I tried this

```
  public interface POSIX extends Library {
    public int chmod(String filename, int mode);
    public int chown(String filename, int userId, int groupId);
    public int chown(String filename, String user, String group);
    }
```

but the after passing the string parameters for user and group, ls -l shows me 806789808 806789776 dor user/group of the file. So is there a way to pass the user and group as Strings ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to pass them as strings, is to

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] { "chown", user, filename });
```

What `chown` does is look up the name for the id before making the system call.

Comment: and btw i have java 6 and exec doesn't get 3 strings as parameters.

Comment: @user2548720 The OS only deals with numbers.  The record on disk only have numbers.  The translation of numbers into names is a job for the tools.  Java 7 doesn't have varargs either, fixing...